# Can jenkins display and/or alter arbitrary text files on the parameterized build screen?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I´m currently working on a solution to generate release notes for a continuously delivered software package at least partly automatic.

We are using a jenkins build server who does all the work. A build occurs at least once a month and is parameterized. I´d like to show the content of the last release notes in the parameterized screen and be able to add new content there.

In addition, i will add a script to search the lastest code commits and add relevant ones also to the release notes.

Is there a solution to

- Show a text file in the parameterized screen.
- Alter a text file in said screen.

This is a requirement, because we´re usually building several release candidates each cycle, so it would be great to "keep" the notes of the previous candidate so we don´t have to enter them again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Reactive Reference Dynamic Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reactive+Reference+Dynamic+Parameter+Controls) plugin.

The name is a bit tricky I know, but in short, it can display anything you wish on the parameterized screen (including HTML & Javascript).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqiZd.png) is a simple configuration I made showing how to display a simple bootstrap HTML table.